# Rails 3 + Devise + Google Omniuth + without confirmation letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, omniauth, google-oauth

Rails 3.0.9
Devise 1.5.3 with confirmable

I am using Devise and Google OAuth2 authentication.
When Google checked login an pass it returned control to my application.

**My problem is: Devise sends a letter with confirmation instructions. But I would like Devise doesn't send such letters for Google accounts only for users are registered through my application.**

**User model is:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

    validates_presence_of :user_name, :address, :tel

    # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
    attr_accessible :user_name, :address, :tel, :attorney_number, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me 

    has_many :eclaims
    has_many :createdtemplates

    before_create do |user|
        user.with_agreement = 1
    end

    def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
        data = access_token.info
        user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

        unless user
            user = User.create(
                       user_name: 'no defined',
                       address: 'no defined',
                       tel: 'no defined',
                       attorney_number: nil,
                       email: data["email"],
                       encrypted_password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                      )
        end
        user
    end 
end
```

**Users::OmniauthCallbacksController**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def google_oauth2
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
          flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        else
          session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end 
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
EFiling2::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"

  devise_for :users, 
    :path_names => { :sign_up => "register", :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" }, 
    :controllers => { 
      :sessions => "sessions", 
      :registrations => "registrations", 
      :confirmations => "confirmations", 
      :passwords => "passwords",
      :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"
    }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `create`...

```
user = User.create(user_name: 'no defined', ...)
```

build the user object so you can call `confirm!`...

```
user = User.new
...
user.confirm!
user.save!
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an addon to noomerikal's answer. You can also use this,

```
user.skip_confirmation!
```

its just a different way of doing pretty much the same thing.